# Mac Mail doesn't work right on Sonoma

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, sonoma

Since updating to Sonoma (one computer from Ventura, the other from Catalina), I have had two problems.

1. Most important. On both computers many emails arrive in Mac Mail (16.0) with the body empty. Web mail works, but I prefer to use Mail app as it helps me carefully file my email in folders.
2. On the computer updated from Catalina I am unable to flag emails at all. On the one updated from Ventura no such problem.

Is there a mail remedy for these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a back up of both machines just in case the issue is not related to Sonoma and instead corruption on the disks. It's less likely both are corrupt in the same way, so having different symptoms tracks with more than one cause (or different errors creeping in the systems over time).

Once you are sure your important data is backed up, turn off all apps that start at launch and reboot.

Next, perform a reindex of mail on each Mac. (noting that attachments will be removed and re-downloaded - so the backup may be needed if you lose an attachment in this rebuild)

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/rebuild-mailboxes-mlhlp1227/mac

For the flagging issue - if it's not fixed - I would open a support case with Apple to see if they have advice - hopefully they can give a little support as part of the recent OS upgrade if the Macs have no warranty support left.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions but the empty email problem seems to have fixed itself - none since the New Year (and since I rebooted a couple of times). And I figured out that I must have inadvertently removed the "flag" column. Put it back, and can now flag normally.

Comment: Hooray! Would you post an answer saying it all cleared up? That way people will know what worked for you and maybe learn something from both our answers @Susiebaby

Comment: Thank you bmike! The problems cleared up without my having to do anything complicated - as per my note above.